# Determine if array is completely sorted

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am currently creating this program in the C language whose purpose is to sort a static array containing multiple elements with a Bubble sort algorithm. Bubble sort may not be a quick and effective algorithm but I am using it for educational purposes.

This program almost works the way I wanted, it's sorting but I am having the following problem:

- My do-while loop keeps repeating even if the array itself is fully sorted. Right now it's looping forever and I want it to stop when the whole array is correctly sorted.

How can I determine whether the whole array is sorted and then stop the iterating when it's fully sorted?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    int list[] = {5,1,5,4,3,2,1};
    int length = sizeof(list) / sizeof(int);

    printf("Unsorted array\n");
    printf("-----------------------------\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (i < length - 1)
            printf("%d, ", list[i]);
        else
            printf("%d", list[i]);
    }

    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {

            if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
            {
                printf("\n* Moving %d and %d", list[i], list[i + 1]);
                int temp = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = list[i];
                list[i] = temp;
            }

            else
            {
                getchar();
            }

            getchar();
        }
        printf("-----------------------------\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (i < length - 1)
                printf("%d, ", list[i]);
            else
                printf("%d", list[i]);
        }

    } while (1);

    printf("Goodbye!\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort explains how to know when to terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think your bubble sort needs to go on for ever?

At the end of one iteration of your inner for loop, the largest element will have "bubbled up" (hence the name) to the end of the array. So you'll know it is in the right place.

Which means that on the next iteration, you only need to bubble sort the first `length - 2` elements. On the third iteration, you'll only need to sort the first `length - 3` elements and so on, until at some point you find yourself sorting the first `length - length` elements. At that point, you know to stop.

So, your `do ... while` loop can be a for loop.

```
for (int sortLength = 1 ; sortLength < length ; ++ sortLength) // replaces your do while loop
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length - sortLength ; ++i)
    {
        // Element swap stuff same as before
    }

    // print loop same as before
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `flag` variable to check, whether there was some exchange in previous iteration. If not, array is already sorted and get of the loop.

```
int flag = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
{

    if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
    {
        printf("\n* Moving %d and %d", list[i], list[i + 1]);
        int temp = list[i + 1];
        list[i + 1] = list[i];
        list[i] = temp;
        flag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        getchar();
    }

     getchar();
}

if (!flag) break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your write :

```
do [...] while (1)
```

this mean that while loop will never end, `1` will be evaluate to `true`, unless there is a break or a goto in the loop (thanks Flikk).

Comment: Unless there is a break or a goto in the loop

Comment: @Flikk but there isn't.

Comment: I am aware of that situation but it was a temporary solution.